# Compile Apache Ambari Error Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.ambari:ambari-metrics-assembly

Tags: ambari

Following the official documentation operation, https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Installation+Guide+for+Ambari+2.7.7

Then run `mvn dependency:resolve` see the error info. How to deal with it?

```bash
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Ambari Main 2.7.7.0.0 .............................. SUCCESS [ 19.469 s]
[INFO] Apache Ambari Project POM 2.7.7.0.0 ................ SUCCESS [  1.469 s]
[INFO] Ambari Web 2.7.7.0.0 ............................... SUCCESS [  0.533 s]
[INFO] Ambari Views 2.7.7.0.0 ............................. SUCCESS [  1.114 s]
[INFO] Ambari Admin View 2.7.7.0.0 ........................ SUCCESS [  0.003 s]
[INFO] ambari-utility 1.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT .................... SUCCESS [ 20.203 s]
[INFO] ambari-metrics 2.7.7.0.0 ........................... SUCCESS [ 59.391 s]
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Common 2.7.7.0.0 .................... SUCCESS [ 11.060 s]
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Hadoop Sink 2.7.7.0.0 ............... SUCCESS [  5.767 s]
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Flume Sink 2.7.7.0.0 ................ SUCCESS [  0.061 s]
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Kafka Sink 2.7.7.0.0 ................ SUCCESS [04:07 min]
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Storm Sink 2.7.7.0.0 ................ SUCCESS [  0.054 s]
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Storm Sink (Legacy) 2.7.7.0.0 ....... SUCCESS [  1.220 s]
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Collector 2.7.7.0.0 ................. SUCCESS [  2.315 s]
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Monitor 2.7.7.0.0 ................... SUCCESS [  6.874 s]
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Grafana 2.7.7.0.0 ................... SUCCESS [  0.007 s]
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Host Aggregator 2.7.7.0.0 ........... SUCCESS [  2.941 s]
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Assembly 2.7.7.0.0 .................. FAILURE [ 23.000 s]
[INFO] Ambari Service Advisor 1.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT ............ SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Server 2.7.7.0.0 ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Functional Tests 2.7.7.0.0 .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Agent 2.7.7.0.0 ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ambari-logsearch 2.7.7.0.0 ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Appender 2.7.7.0.0 ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Config Api 2.7.7.0.0 .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Config JSON 2.7.7.0.0 ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Config Solr 2.7.7.0.0 ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Config Zookeeper 2.7.7.0.0 ........ SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Config Local 2.7.7.0.0 ............ SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Log Feeder Plugin Api 2.7.7.0.0 ... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Log Feeder Container Registry 2.7.7.0.0 SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Log Feeder 2.7.7.0.0 .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Web 2.7.7.0.0 ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Server 2.7.7.0.0 .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Assembly 2.7.7.0.0 ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Integration Test 2.7.7.0.0 ........ SKIPPED
[INFO] ambari-infra 2.7.7.0.0 ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Infra Solr Client 2.7.7.0.0 ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Infra Solr Plugin 2.7.7.0.0 ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Infra Manager 2.7.7.0.0 ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Infra Assembly 2.7.7.0.0 .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Infra Manager Integration Tests 2.7.7.0.0 ... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  06:48 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-11-03T13:59:34+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project ambari-metrics-assembly: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.ambari:ambari-metrics-assembly:pom:2.7.7.0.0: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.ambari:ambari-metrics-timelineservice:jar:2.7.7.0.0 (absent), org.apache.ambari:ambari-metrics-host-aggregator:jar:2.7.7.0.0 (absent): org.apache.ambari:ambari-metrics-timelineservice:jar:2.7.7.0.0 was not found in https://repo.hortonworks.com/content/groups/releases/ during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of apache-hadoop has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project ambari-metrics-assembly: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.ambari:ambari-metrics-assembly:pom:2.7.7.0.0: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.ambari:ambari-metrics-timelineservice:jar:2.7.7.0.0 (absent), org.apache.ambari:ambari-metrics-host-aggregator:jar:2.7.7.0.0 (absent): org.apache.ambari:ambari-metrics-timelineservice:jar:2.7.7.0.0 was not found in https://repo.hortonworks.com/content/groups/releases/ during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of apache-hadoop has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:243)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:136)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved (MojoExecutor.java:355)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:313)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.ambari:ambari-metrics-assembly:pom:2.7.7.0.0: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.ambari:ambari-metrics-timelineservice:jar:2.7.7.0.0 (absent), org.apache.ambari:ambari-metrics-host-aggregator:jar:2.7.7.0.0 (absent): org.apache.ambari:ambari-metrics-timelineservice:jar:2.7.7.0.0 was not found in https://repo.hortonworks.com/content/groups/releases/ during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of apache-hadoop has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve (DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:187)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:224)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:136)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved (MojoExecutor.java:355)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:313)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.ambari:ambari-metrics-timelineservice:jar:2.7.7.0.0 (absent), org.apache.ambari:ambari-metrics-host-aggregator:jar:2.7.7.0.0 (absent): org.apache.ambari:ambari-metrics-timelineservice:jar:2.7.7.0.0 was not found in https://repo.hortonworks.com/content/groups/releases/ during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of apache-hadoop has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:365)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve (DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:182)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:224)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:136)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved (MojoExecutor.java:355)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:313)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.ambari:ambari-metrics-timelineservice:jar:2.7.7.0.0 (absent), org.apache.ambari:ambari-metrics-host-aggregator:jar:2.7.7.0.0 (absent): org.apache.ambari:ambari-metrics-timelineservice:jar:2.7.7.0.0 was not found in https://repo.hortonworks.com/content/groups/releases/ during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of apache-hadoop has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:353)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve (DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:182)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:224)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:136)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved (MojoExecutor.java:355)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:313)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: org.apache.ambari:ambari-metrics-timelineservice:jar:2.7.7.0.0 was not found in https://repo.hortonworks.com/content/groups/releases/ during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of apache-hadoop has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException (DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact (DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:586)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:525)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:353)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve (DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:182)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:224)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:136)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved (MojoExecutor.java:355)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:313)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :ambari-metrics-assembly
[DEBUG] Shutting down adapter factory; available factories [file-lock, rwlock-local, semaphore-local, noop]; available name mappers [discriminating, file-gav, file-hgav, file-static, gav, static]
[DEBUG] Shutting down 'file-lock' factory
[DEBUG] Shutting down 'rwlock-local' factory
[DEBUG] Shutting down 'semaphore-local' factory
[DEBUG] Shutting down 'noop' factory
```

workflow such as:

```bash
wget https://dlcdn.apache.org/ambari/ambari-2.7.7/apache-ambari-2.7.7-src.tar.gz
tar xf apache-ambari-2.7.7-src.tar.gz
cd apache-ambari-2.7.7-src/

mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=2.7.7.0.0
pushd ambari-metrics
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=2.7.7.0.0
popd

mvn -B clean install rpm:rpm -DnewVersion=2.7.7.0.0 -DbuildNumber=388e072381e71c7755673b7743531c03a4d61be8 -DskipTests -Dpython.ver="python >= 2.6" -Drat.skip=true
```

The build prompts for missing dependencies, but according to the official website, the required dependencies are already installed, is it possible that the dependencies are missing from the Maven repository?

modified part:

https://github.com/apache/ambari/pull/3722/files
https://github.com/apache/ambari/pull/3686/files

Answer (score 0):

if you change the version from `-DnewVersion=2.7.7.0.0` to `-DnewVersion=2.7.3.2.19` it will fix that error. The links to version `-DnewVersion=2.7.7.0.0` are no longer available!
[Here is the proof](https://imgur.com/ppxglmC.png)